# Assessing the error when replacing post-inverse with pre-inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Given a symmetric matrix $H$ which is already "close to" diagonal. Now a matrix $G$ can be found such that, when multiplied from the left:

$$
G H = I
$$

This implies $G=H^{-1}$ and hence multiplying $H$ from the right yields the same result:

$$
H G = H (H^{-1}) = I
$$

Now the question is: Suppose $G'$ is found such that it does not perfectly diagonalize, i.e.:

$$
G'  H \approx I
$$

Can anything be said about $H G'$? In particular, how far off from being diagonal will $G' H$ as compared to $G' H$?

I guess this also requires some sort of "diagonally" measure. For now I would take the L2 norm of the diagonal elements of a matrix M$M divided by the L2 norm of the rest:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N |M_{ii}|^2 }{\sum_{i \neq j} |M_{ij}|^2}}
$$

but any other meaningful measure would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition. Nothing can be said about $HG-I$, except if $H$ is not too badly conditioned.

Proof. Let $G=H^{-1}+U$; then $GH=I+UH$ where $\Delta=UH$ is small. Note that $||U||\leq ||\Delta||||H^{-1}||$ and that, if $H$ has small eigenvalues, then $||H^{-1}||$ may be large and $U$ may be large.

Finally, $HG=I+HU$ and $||HU||\leq ||\Delta||cond(H)$ is not necessarily small (except if $cond(H)$ is "reasonable").

Example: $H=\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon&\epsilon\\\epsilon&1\end{pmatrix},U=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&\epsilon\end{pmatrix}$ where $\epsilon$ is small. $\square$

Comment: Nice answer! I've a couple of questions/remarks though: 1.) I mentioned that $H$ is already "close to diagonal" (i.e., the diagonals will be about a factor 5-10 higher than off diagonals). Does this imply "not too badly conditioned"? Also, the $H$ is your example would not happen in my setup because $H$ is already close to diagonal.

Comment: 2.) I am sure this is trivial but where does $\|U\| \leq \|\Delta\|\|H^{-1}\|$ and $\|H U\| \leq \|\Delta\| \operatorname{cond}(H)$ come from?

Comment: 3.) I think my actual question would relate to the part "EXCEPT if $H$ is not too badly conditioned". To my understanding, you showed that nothing can be said if $H$ is not well behaved but what can be said if it is?

Comment: 1). My $H$ is close to a diagonal matrix; moreover its eigenvalues are $\approx 1,\epsilon$ and $cond(H)\approx 1/\epsilon$, that is a large number.  2) Use $||AB||\leq ||A||||B||$.   3) If $GH=I$ with $k$ digits and $cond(H)\approx 10^p$, then $HG=I$ with at least $k-p$ digits.